# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que 3 'for' impriman sincronizados?

Tags: python, matrices

(Todos son Matrices)
Mi problema es que necesito que se imprima la primera línea de todos los 'for' al mismo tiempo, la segunda línea de todos los 'for' al mismo tiempo y así sucesivamente, por ejemplo yo ingreso una matriz de 3, y me imprime 9 resultados en ves de 3, ¿Cómo corrijo esto?

```
    for i, fila in enumerate(copia):
        for t, filita in enumerate(medica):
            for d, filota in enumerate(pacientes):
                print(i + 1)
                me1 = fila.index(min(fila))
                me = int(me1)
                me +=1
                ma = fila.index(max(fila))
                ma1 = int(ma)
                ma +=1
                print(me, min(fila))
                print(ma, max(fila))
                print(f'{min(filita):.2f} {sum(filita) / k:.2f} {max(filita):.2f}') 
                print(f'{sum(filota) / suma:.2f}')
ti = tipo.index(min(tipo))
ti1 = int(ti)
ti1 +=1
tii = tipo.index(max(tipo))
ti2 = int(tii)
ti2 +=1
print(ti1, min(tipo))
print(ti2, max(tipo))
```

También probé usando los for de esta forma: pero ahora me imprime todas las matrices separadas, en ves de como lo requiero, incluso metí los otros dos for dentro del primero, pero no se imprimen en orden.

```
for i, fila in enumerate(copia):
    print(i + 1)
    me1 = fila.index(min(fila))
    me = int(me1)
    me +=1
    ma = fila.index(max(fila))
    ma1 = int(ma)
    ma +=1
    print(me, min(fila))
    print(ma, max(fila))
for t, filita in enumerate(medica):
    print(f'{min(filita):.2f} {sum(filita) / k:.2f} {max(filita):.2f}')
for d, filota in enumerate(pacientes):
    print(f'{sum(filota) / suma:.2f}')
```

Comment: Haz la lógica e imprime las cosas de fila en el scope de fila. Las cosas de filita hazlas e imprímelas ahí. Las cosas que solo tengan relación con filota deben ir en el for de filota. Si haces todo en el for mas anidado, vas a repetir el print una y otra vez.

Comment: ¿todas las matrices tienen el mismo largo?

Comment: pon los `print()` en su bloque correspondiente

Comment: para mi estas usando dos for de más con uno solo se podría solucionar

Comment: @tincopasan, que propones que pueda hacer? intenté con un solo for, pero las matrices tienen informacion distinta cada una (son del mismo tamaño)

Comment: Si son del mismo tamaño se puede utilizar el `for i in range()`

Comment: ya te van  a hacer una respuesta pero la mía es partiendo de: for x in range(len(copia1)): #suponiendo que no sepas el largo
    
    print(copia1[x].index(min(copia1[x]))) y es la misma asignación para las otras matrices, además no necesitas enumerate, lo usas del índice de range

Comment: una pregunta, que hace tu codigo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres imprimir el mismo índice de cada lista, no iteres de manera independiente por ellas, sino haz un solo ciclo for sobre una variable entera para usarla como índice. En cada iteración extraes el i-esimo elemento de cada lista para imprimir.

Para determinar el rango por el cual iterar, puedes valerte de la función `len()` para determinar la longitud de la lista. Si las listas no son del mismo tamaño, utiliza `min()` para obtener la longitud de la lista de menor tamaño, ya que acceder a índices inexistentes lanzaría un error.

He preparado el siguiente ejemplo para que lo veas en código,

```
lista1 = ('uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro')
lista2 = ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five')
lista3 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)


for i in range(min(len(lista1), len(lista2), len(lista3))):
    print(lista1[i])
    print(lista2[i])
    print(lista3[i])
    print('-----------')
```

La salida que produce es:

```
uno
one
1
-----------
dos
two
2
-----------
tres
three
3
-----------
cuatro
four
4
-----------
```

Otra forma de imprimirlo:

```
for i in range(min(len(lista1), len(lista2), len(lista3))):
    print(lista1[i], lista2[i], lista3[i])
```

produce:

```
uno one 1
dos two 2
tres three 3
cuatro four 4
```